# React Native - When Input is focused and all modal layout push up

Tags: react-native, native-base

I have encountered an issue when one of my input inside the modal inner layout is being focused, my modal inner layout will automatically push up. I would like to prevent when my one of input in the modal is being focused, it should not automatically push up my modal inner layout.

You may watch the video that I try to illustrate through the above statement: https://streamable.com/83yk13

Attemption:
KeyboardAvoidingView,[react-native-android-keyboard-adjust](https://github.com/zubricky/react-native-android-keyboard-adjust)

I have attempted the above 2 implementations but it does not show any differences.

Environment:
"react-native": "0.63.3",
"native-base": "^2.13.15"